# Java: Search in a wrong encoded String without modifying it

Tags: java, utf-8, latin1

I have to find a user-defined String in a Document (using **Java**), which is stored in a database in a BLOB. When I search a String with special characters ("Umlaute", äöü etc.), it failes, meaning it does not return any positions at all. And I am not allowed to convert the document's content into UTF-8 (which would have fixed this problem but raised a new, even bigger one).

Some additional information:
The document's content is returned as String in "ISO-8859-1" (Latin1).
Here is an example, what a String could look like:

```
Die Erkenntnis, daÃ der KÃ¼nstler Schutz braucht, ...
```

This is how it should look like:

```
Die Erkenntnis, daß der Künstler Schutz braucht, ...
```

If I am searching for `Künstler` it would fail to find it, because it looks for `ü` but only finds `Ã¼`.

Is it possible to convert `Künstler` into `KÃ¼nstler` so I can search for the wrong encoded version instead?

*Note:*
We are using the Hibernate Framework for Database access. The original Getter for the Document's Content returns a `byte[]`. The String is than returned by calling

```
new String(getContent(), "ISO-8859-1")
```

The problem here is, that I cannot change this to UTF-8, because it would then mess up the rest of our application which is based on a third party application that delivers data this way.

Comment: If you sure the DB contains Latin-1 encoded data, you can get the bytes from Künstler using `"Künstler".getBytes("ISO-8859-1")`, though the `Ã¼` looks like two characters which is not the case in Latin-1 for `ü`.

Comment: @GáborBakos The problem there is, that I need the comperator String (`Künstler` for that matter) as a **String**. If I convert the Byte Array back, the result is still `Künstler` but I need `KÃ¼nstler`.
Looks like messing up an encoding on purpose is harder than thought :D

Comment: Please show more code like how you are searching and pulling data from the blob.

Comment: What are you storing it as a BLOB rather than TEXT in the DB? And if you insist on storing it as a BLOB, you should add an encoding column so you know how to decode it. Also, if it's a BLOB, you should get it as a byte[] in Java and then decode it, not get it as a String using a mystery encoding.

Comment: The problem there is that the DB is "dictated" by a third party application. So we mustn't modify the DB in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, looks like I've found a way to mess up the encoding on purpose.

```
new String("Künstler".getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1")
```

By getting the Bytes of the String `Künstler` in UTF-8 and then creating a new String, telling Java that this is Latin1, it converts to `KÃ¼nstler`. It's a hell of a hack but seems to work well.

Answer (score 0):

Already answered by yourself.

**An altoghether different approach:**
If you can search the blob, you could search using

```
"SELECT .. FROM ... WHERE"
+ " ... LIKE '%" + key.replaceAll("\\P{Ascii}+", "%") + "%'"
```

This replaces non-ASCII sequences by the `%` wildcard: UTF-8 multibyte sequences are non-ASCII by design.